# Is it safe to uninstall `su` in favor of `sudo` to harden Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, sudo, su, hardening

Is it safe to uninstall `su` in favor of `sudo` to harden Arch Linux?

Have you got an opinion on whether this is a good or bad idea?

I read the Arch Linux Wiki articles [Security](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Security), [Su](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Su) and [Sudo](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo). I also searched for further resources with regards to this matter but couldn't find any substantial information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing setuid/setgid from system applications isn't done routinely (though there are occasional guidelines which do suggest just that).  Doing this invalidates the package configuration, making it necessary for someone to make special-cases when investigating discrepancies between package content and the installed system.

The usual approach is to not configure root's password (so that it is effectively unknown), and to configure a non-root *administrator* for the machine using `sudo`.